# How many distinct chromatic polynomials are there for simple connected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

For a given order $n$, the number of graphs that are determined uniquely by their  [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) is [A137568](http://oeis.org/A137568). This sequence starting with n=1 is:

```
1, 2, 4, 7, 16, 41, 139, 704, 7270, 183606
```

I am looking for something slightly different, the sequence formed by the number of **distinct chromatic polynomials** for **connected** graphs.

Comment: The definition given at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticallyUniqueGraph.html is that this sequence lists the number of graphs which have a unique polynomial, not the number of different polynomials...

Comment: I have verified the above numbers for general graphs up to 8 vertices and for connected graphs the sequence of chromatically unique graphs is 1, 1, 2, 4, 10, 27, 100, 570.

Comment: @Jernej I thought your answer was useful and may even be what Hooked was looking for, hopefully we will find out!

Comment: @jp26 I agree! I was only waiting a few days before I accepted the answer to see if someone could come up with a reference with a longer set of terms. Independently I've computed this up to n=10 (without using Sage), so I'll post it as an answer if no one else does.

Comment: so are you looking for the numbers of different chromatic polynomials or the numbers of graphs with unique chromatic polynomials?

Comment: @jp26 I am looking for the number of unique _polynomials_ not the number of unique graphs. I just realized that the title and the text contradict each other. I'll make an edit to correct this. However, the other question is very interesting too and worth asking in it's own right.